# Mysql multiple domains

Tags: mysql

I am configuring mysql for my server, but I have one question: Is it possible for each domain to see their own mysql server, but only having to run one service at the server? I want to keep all databases for the domains separated, but I don't want to have to prefix each database name.

eg: suppose I have domain1.com and a domain2.com running on the same server. For both domains I want a database called statistics.
If I want to do this now, I'll have to prefix the databases, so there are two databases: domain1_statistics and domain2_statistics, and the domains can only access their own databases. But I want to create 2 databases called statistics, one for each domain, so that each domain only sees its own statistics database. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only achieve this if you run multiple servers (on different ports) with [mysqld-multi](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqld-multi.html)

Comment: It isn't possible to create virtual servers or something like that? Multiple instances would probably create a large overhead...

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have multiple databases with the same name in one mysql server instance. I would suggest merging the statistics tables into the domain's own database. Otherwise, you could prefix the tables for each domain within 1 statistics database. Which method you use depends on how and who you want to be able to access the statistics data

Comment: ok tx, the statistics database was just an example, but I have my answer now!